# Manipulating reactive objects in Shiny - Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm running into the error "Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment" over and over again as I attempt to take a reactive object in Shiny and further manipulate it. I've provided an illustrative example below.

```
 testdf <- data.frame(row1 = c(1,3,6), row2 = c(7, 5, 1))

 ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Education in Tanzania"),

   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(


       #Select aggregation level of data
       selectInput("AggregationSelect", 
                   label = "Aggregation",
                   choices = list("School" = 1, 
                                  "District" = 2, 
                                  "Region" = 3),
                   selected = 1)
     ),

     mainPanel(
       DT::dataTableOutput("OutputTable")
     )
   )
 )

 server <- function(input, output) {

     Output1 <- reactive({
         testdf
     })

   observe({
     if(2 %in% input$AggregationSelect) {
       observe({Output1()$name[3] <- "b"})
     } else  if(3 %in% input$AggregationSelect) {
       observe({Output1()$name[2] <- "c"})
     } else  if(1 %in% input$AggregationSelect) {
       observe({Output1()$name[1] <- "a"})
     }
   })

   output$OutputTable <- {DT::renderDataTable({
     DT::datatable(Output1(),
                   options = list(pagelength = 25,
                                  searching = TRUE,
                                  paging = TRUE,
                                  lengthChange = FALSE),
                   rownames = FALSE)
     })
   }
 }  

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I need to do in my actual code is assemble a dataframe through the UI (which I am able to do and therefore have just subbed a random df in here) and then add some information (represented here with the added "names" column) based on what has been selected in the UI. It seems like it shouldn't be all that difficult to add a column to a df, but within the reactive object context, nothing I have attempted has worked. Other ways to modify reactive objects are welcome as long as they can be applied to more complex multi-step scenarios - there's no way I can get everything I need bundled into the initial assignment of the reactive object.

Comment: U dont have a variable called `name` in `testdf`

Answer (score 1):

1. Reactive expressions cannot be modified from outside. You can only modify reactive values.
2. Generally you should never need to use `observe`. Use reactive expression if you don't need side effect, use reactive values with `observeEvent` when needed.
3. You **must** read reactive tutorials before going forward. There are quite some concepts need to be understood before you can do anything complex, especially the "force update habit". You need to let Shiny do the update properly and setup the logic correctly.

I suggest you read all the tutorials, articles about reactive in RStudio website, then watch [the reactive tutorial video in Shiny conference](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/).

Comment: This error isn't specific to Shiny or reactive.  You can get it in plain R.  E.g., `bogus() <- 4`  gives `Error in bogus() <- 4 : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment`.

Comment: That's totally different with the question as the error message is generic. Your example is trying to modify a function call which is not valid synyax.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% what you're doing but I think its best if you use `eventReactive` that would listen to your `selectInput`. Note that I added the variable `names` to the dataframe:

```
library(shiny)
testdf <- data.frame(names = c(1,3,6), row2 = c(7, 5, 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Education in Tanzania"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Select aggregation level of data
      selectInput("AggregationSelect", label = "Aggregation",
                  choices = list("School" = 1, "District" = 2, "Region" = 3),selected = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("OutputTable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Output1 <- eventReactive(input$AggregationSelect,{
    if(input$AggregationSelect %in% "2"){
      testdf$name[3] <- "b"
      return(testdf)
    }
    else if(input$AggregationSelect %in% "3"){
      testdf$name[2] <- "c"
      return(testdf)
    }
    else if(input$AggregationSelect %in% "1"){
      testdf$name[1] <- "a"
      return(testdf)
    }
    else{
      return(testdf)
    }
  })

  output$OutputTable <- {DT::renderDataTable({
    print(Output1())
    DT::datatable(Output1(),options = list(pagelength = 25,searching = TRUE,paging = TRUE,lengthChange = FALSE),rownames = FALSE)
  })
  }
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: The testdf was just for an example. What I have is already a reactive object (a dataframe) that I THEN need to manipulate, which is why I was working with Output1. Appreciate the shortcut, but it won't work for my actual code because I don't have a dataframe to start with

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your problem, i've tweaked you code as following :

```
testdf <- data.frame(name = c(1,2,3), freq = c(100, 200, 300))

ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Education in Tanzania"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(


  #Select aggregation level of data
  selectInput("AggregationSelect", 
              label = "Aggregation",
              choices = list("School" = 1, 
                             "District" = 2, 
                             "Region" = 3))
),

mainPanel(
  DT::dataTableOutput("OutputTable")
 )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

Output1 <- reactive({
input$AggregationSelect
selection <- input$AggregationSelect

if(2 %in% selection){
  testdf$name[3] <- "b"
} 
else if(3 %in% selection){
  testdf$name[2] <- "c"
} 
else if(1 %in% selection){
  testdf$name[1] <- "a"
}
testdf
})

output$OutputTable <- {DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(Output1(),
              options = list(pagelength = 25,
                             searching = TRUE,
                             paging = TRUE,
                             lengthChange = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
})
}}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: app]

Comment: The testdf was just for an example. What I have is already a reactive object (a dataframe) that I THEN need to manipulate, which is why I was working with Output1. Appreciate the shortcut, but it won't work for my actual code...

Comment: @Clare , Do you need to manipulate a larger reactive dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, much larger data frame that requires manipulation (getting some stats based on the whole df, assigning factor levels according to the outcome) AFTER it's been assembled.